# Re-add Cyanogenmod's CustomTile after it was manually removed

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I'm toying with a very simple app that just adds a quick settings tile using [Cyanogenmod CustomTile API](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/cm_platform_sdk/wiki/Custom-Tiles).

Everything works (my app's code closely resembles the [CM SDK sample app](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/cm_platform_sdk/tree/cm-13.0/samples/customtiles)), except for a single scenario. The problem is, once I've manually removed the tile I can't find any way to add it back.

I've tapped "edit tiles" and deleted my app's tile. Now calls to `CMStatusBarManager.publishTile` don't seem to have any effect (I've surely tried to restart the app) and the only tiles listed for manual addition are the system ones. Uninstalling the app and re-installing it works, but I want to handle this scenario in somewhat more user-friendly fashion.

It would be best if I only could register the tile to be listed along the system ones in "edit tiles" mode, but I guess there's no API for this at the moment. Another acceptable solution is a way to re-add the tile (I'll just show a warning that tile was removed and a button to re-add it).

The question is specifically about CyanogenMod 12.1 and 13. Right now I don't care about any upcoming Android N stuff — I just want to make a user-level application specifically for CM-based ROMs of a certain phone have a feature and be on par with stock ROM.